# Query many to many relation using slim framework and doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, slim

I am using Slim Framework with Doctrine. I have three Tables

```
id | username | password | name
--------------------------------
1  | Lorel    | ******** | Lorel

id | permission  | description
-------------------------------
2  | READ_ACCESS | Lorel Ipsum


id | user_id | permission_id
-----------------------------
X  | 1       | 2
```

Is there anyway using doctrine through which I can find out, suppose if user '1' has permission '2'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking to do Authorization. I've got a setup which does that, in Zend Framework 3 with Doctrine 2. The relations are the same, just not sure how to translate it to Slim Framework. But here goes nothing ;-)

**User** Entity has a relation to Roles:

```
/**
 * @var Collection|ArrayCollection|Role[]
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User\Entity\Role", inversedBy="users", fetch="LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="user_user_roles",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 *
 */
protected $roles;
```

**Role** Entity has Routes and the inverse side to **User**

```
/**
 * @var Collection|ArrayCollection|Route[]
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User\Entity\Route", inversedBy="roles", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="user_role_routes",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="route_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $routes;

/**
 * @var Collection|ArrayCollection|User[]
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User\Entity\User", mappedBy="roles", fetch="LAZY")
 */
protected $users;
```

**Route** Entity just has the inverse to **Role**

```
/**
 * @var Collection|ArrayCollection|Role[]
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User\Entity\Role", mappedBy="routes", fetch="LAZY")
 */
protected $roles;
```

Notice that it concerns **2** relationships:

- User <-> Role
- Role <-> Route

Make sure to initialize each Collection in the `__construct`, like so:

```
// Initialize only those within the Entity
public function __construct()
{ 
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Generate your **getter** method (setter not required!). Create Adder/Remover methods instead of a setter, like so (this is within **Route** Entity):

```
/**
 * @param Collection|ArrayCollection|Role[] $roles
 *
 * @return Route
 */
public function addRoles(Collection $roles) : Route
{
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if ( ! $this->getRoles()->contains($role)) {
            $this->getRoles()->add($role);
        }

        if ( ! $role->getRoutes()->contains($this)) {
            $role->getRoutes()->add($this);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param Collection|ArrayCollection|Role[] $roles
 *
 * @return Route
 */
public function removeRoles(Collection $roles) : Route
{
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if ($this->getRoles()->contains($role)) {
            $this->getRoles()->remove($role);
        }

        if ($role->getRoutes()->contains($this)) {
            $role->getRoutes()->remove($this);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

---

So, there you go, that's the setup. I would advise you to include [Gedmo Doctrine extensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) and apply the `@Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")` to your **Role** Entity. Makes managing (nested/inherited) roles easy. See [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) (and [Gedmo Tree docs](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/tree.md#entity-mapping))

---

To next check if a User has access to a certain Route you need some form of AuthenticationService. Because I don't know Slim, make sure you fill this in with something from that framework. The logic is the same though. I use a service to be included/used on route access that checks if the User is known (Authenticated), and if not assigns a Guest Role, and then checks if the Route to be accessed is known to any of the assigned roles.

```
/**
 * @param string $route
 *
 * @return bool
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function isGranted(string $route) : bool
{
    // Get assigned Role[] array or set Guest Role
    if ($this->getAuthenticationService()->hasIdentity()) {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->getAuthenticationService()->getIdentity();

        /** @var Collection|Role[] $roles */
        $roles = $user->getRoles();
    } else {
        $roles = new ArrayCollection(
            [
                $this->getObjectManager()->getRepository(Role::class)->findOneBy(['name' => Role::NO_ACCOUNT_ROLE]),
            ]
        );
    }

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if ($this->checkRoutes($role, $route)) {

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

So, all of the above should get you more than going I'd say.

GL & HF